What is the purpose of signed comparisons with LLONG_MIN?
Looking at a 64-bit PE executable, I found the following fragment:
    mov    rdi,8000000000000000h    ; LLONG_MIN
    cmp    rax,rdi
    jle    1800047A6h

I don't understand the purpose of comparing rax with LLONG_MIN and using the jle (signed less-or-equal). Wouldn't every value of rax be (signed) greater than LLONG_MIN except LLONG_MIN itself? If so, why wouldn't a je suffice?

If jle and je are equivalent here (I think they are) then je isn't better (nor worse) on modern processors, there was a difference on Core2 (cmp \ jle couldn't macro-fuse on Core2, cmp \ je could but not in 64-bit code)
